# Removing Data Points From a Chart Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

This question is in reference removing data points from a chart using VBA.

After an extensive search, I have come across some very usefull code. In particular from Jon Peltier (Get Information about a point in an embedded chart):

Unfortunetly, this code only returns the series name and value of the data point (very useful, but need to take it a step further). To make this code a little more robust, it would ideally return the cell location of the selected data point (upon which it could be highlighted, deleted, etc.). The exact same question was asked on another forum some time ago, but with no solution (see links at ozgrid, link below)

Essentially, I would need to extract the cell address from the series name and data point so I can write a section of code to clear the contents of the cell, and thereby remove the data point from the chart.  Any ideas? i.e. portion of code to update:

```
'Sheet4.Cells(b, ????).ClearContents
```

Thanks for any input!

This question was also asked in:

http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=181251&goto=newpost**

(with links to Jon Pelteir and other references)

The full code is:

```
Private Sub EvtChart_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, _ 
ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) 
 'extracted and modified from [URL]http://www.computorcompanion.com/LPMArticle.asp?ID=221[/URL]

Dim ElementID As Long 
Dim a As Long 
Dim b As Long 
Dim msg As String 
Dim myX As Date 
Dim myY As Double 
Dim Answer As Integer 
Dim Counter As Integer 
Dim QAFDest As Range 
Dim NoRows As Integer 
With ActiveChart 
     ' Pass x & y, return ElementID and Args
    .GetChartElement x, y, ElementID, a, b 
    If ElementID = xlSeries Then 
        If b > 0 Then 
             ' Extract x value from array of x values
            myX = WorksheetFunction.Index _ 
            (.SeriesCollection(a).XValues, b) 
             ' Extract y value from array of y values
            myY = WorksheetFunction.Index _ 
            (.SeriesCollection(a).Values, b) 

             ' Display message box with point information
            msg = "You are about to remove the following point from data Series " & vbCrLf _ 
            & """" & .SeriesCollection(a).Name & """" & vbCrLf _ 
            & "Point " & b & vbCrLf _ 
            & "Value = " & myY & vbCrLf _ 
            & "Continue?" 
            If MsgBox(msg, vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then 
                 'Sheet4.Cells(b, ????).ClearContents
            End If 
        End If 
    End If 
End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: What type of chart are you using?

Comment: a simple scatter chart, with only one data series (see a few more comments below)

Answer (score 1):

***(Note: I'm not sure how your chart is set up, so the range returned may vary).***

To return the range given the selection on the chart, you can do the following:

```
Set seriesParts = Split(.SeriesCollection(a).Formula)
Set ySeriesAddress = seriesParts(2)
set ySeriesRange = Range(ySeriesAddress)
```

From here, depending on the type of chart you have, you can use *`arg1`* and *`arg2`* values of the `GetChartElement` method to select the cell(s) containing the data that you want to delete.

For example if you had a simple chart and data like below

[image: Sample Chart Data]

and the point selected was Point C (index of 3), you would use the following code

```
Set seriesParts = Split(.SeriesCollection(a).Formula)
Set ySeriesAddress = seriesParts(2)
' The code below would return the range "B2:B9
set ySeriesRange = Range(ySeriesAddress)
ySeriesRange(b).ClearContents
```

This would clear the value "3" from the chart data

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get a some code runinng without using the `set` function.  See below:

```
Private Sub EmbChart_MouseUp _
(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long)

Dim ElementID As Long, Arg1 As Long, Arg2 As Long
Dim myX As Double, myY As Double

Dim SF As String
Dim splitArray() As String

Dim row As Long
Dim column As String

If Button = xlPrimaryButton Then
With EmbChart
'Pass x & y, return ElementID and Args
    .GetChartElement X, Y, ElementID, Arg1, Arg2

    Application.StatusBar = "[" & ElementID & "]" 'delete?

    If ElementID = xlSeries Or ElementID = xlDataLabel Then
        If Arg2 > 0 Then
                ' Extract x value from array of x values
            myX = WorksheetFunction.Index(.SeriesCollection(Arg1).XValues, Arg2)
                ' Extract y value from array of y values
            myY = WorksheetFunction.Index(.SeriesCollection(Arg1).Values, Arg2)

            Application.StatusBar = "[" & myX & ", " & myY & "]"

                  'find row of selected chart point
                   row = myX + 3                            'dependant on starting row of data


                  'find row of selected chart point
                   SF = .SeriesCollection(Arg1).Formula     'return series formula as string
                   splitArray() = Split(SF, "$")            'split series formula into array with $ as deliminter
                   column = splitArray(3)                   'return selected column


                   Debug.Print column


                   'delete and highlight corresponding cell

                ActiveSheet.Cells(row, column).ClearContents
                ActiveSheet.Cells(row, column).Interior.Color = vbYellow

       End If

    End If

Application.StatusBar = False


End With
End If
End Sub
```